# Jest with special tests run on occasion

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

How do I write Jest tests that only runs when specifically invoked on the command line?

I want to have integration-like tests that interact with online services from Google and Amazon in a React project.

If I create a differently named test file **src/google.itest.js**:

- Good: It is not normally run by jest
- Good: It resides where all other tests are
- Bad: **jest** cannot be made to run it:

`jest --testPathPattern="\.itest"`
Jest still does not run the tests, probably because it is blocked by the **testMatch** configuration option:
testMatch:

`**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)`

How do I write Jest tests that only runs when specifically invoked on the command line?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to avoid calling real services, usually it is a bad practice to call the real services from a test, maybe you need to mock that service?

Comment: @felixmosh These are integration tests, it is perfectly reasonable to call a real service as part of an integration test.

Answer (score 3):

It works with RegExp (presumably those are ECMAScript regexps):

`jest --testRegex 'src/.*itest.*'`

Note that an equal sign separating the long option and its value is not required